# Can I isolate virtual machines from each other on a physical host?

Tags: server, virtual, firewall, hyper-v

I have a virtual server (Windows Server 2016) on a Host (commercial virtual server hosting). It places on Hyper-V. The problem is: I see the other virtual machines on the physical host (like on a local network), and other SQL servers on the network. Is it normal? I turned off the network browsing, and haided the machine from network, but  I don't think this is the correct solution.

The company told me that, I can separate the machine on the Windows Firewall. Is it true?

So, can I isolate the machine from other virtual machines, while remains the access from the internet to the machine?

Thanks,

Tomipont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network discovery in Hyper-V depends on how you define network between your machines in Hyper-V manager. Take a look at Virtual Switch Manager in Hyper-V manager and check  what is set in network adapter of each machine.
There are three different Hyper-V virtual switch types that are used to connect Hyper-V virtual machine NICs:

```
External Virtual Switch
Internal Virtual Switch
Private Virtual Switch
```

Also Hyper-V VLAN technology enables logical segmentation of networks, meaning that you can take a single switch and divide it into multiple logical networks. Note that the traffic of each network runs in isolation. Therefore, even though all virtual networks share the same hardware, Hyper-V VLANs can identify and read only their own network traffic. In truth, each virtual network is unaware of other virtual networks and is disconnected from them.

Comment: Hi Afshin, Thanks for your reply. I will ask the cloud provider about these settings, because I have only one virtual machine on Hyper-V, and I think I can't access to these settings.